# Share only a single folder using SMB

Tags: windows-7, windows, networking, smb

I want to share my "My Videos" folder using Windows's built in SMB. The problem is that when I decide to share my video folder and check it on another device, the path always is:

```
networkname > username > My Videos
```

instead of just:

```
My Videos
```

I noticed that indeed sharing gets turned on from the user folder down to the video folder instead of just on the folder I selected.

Why is this happening? How can I just display the "My Videos" folder on my remote device and not the entire path? The device in question is a hacked Apple TV.

Comment: Why do you want to change this? Is there an error because of this path?

Comment: because each time I need to click trough 3 levels of UI to get to the video folder